# Запись в куку php

Tags: php, cookie

Есть кука $_COOKIE. Print_r выдаёт следующую структуру

```
   Array
    (
        [NAME] => "name", 
        [INFO] => {"COUNTRY_CODE":"RU","CITY_ID":"780"}
    )
```

Мне нужно изменить значение info для этого пишу

```
$INFO_NEW[] = json_decode( $_COOKIE["INFO"], true );

$INFO_NEW[0]["CITY_NAME"] = "WWW";
$INFO_NEW[0]["CITY_ID"] = "55";

setcookie($_COOKIE["INFO"],json_encode($INFO_NEW));
```

Но значение не изменилось, подскажите что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: А вы прочитайте, что в первом параметре функции setcookie() передается http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php.

Comment: я написал вот так setcookie("INFO", json_encode($INFO_NEW)); но ничего не изменилось

Comment: 1. Если перед вызовом функции клиенту уже передавался какой-либо вывод (тэги, пустые строки, пробелы, текст и т.п.), setcookie() вызовет отказ и вернет FALSE. 2. Cookie станут видимыми только после перезагрузки страницы, для которой они должны быть видны. Для проверки, правильно ли cookie установились, проверьте их при следующей загрузке страницы до истечения срока их действия. Срок действия cookie задается в параметре expire. Удобно проверять существование cookie простым вызовом print_r($_COOKIE);.