# setcookie после передачи разметки без ошибки Warning

Tags: php, warning

Часто встречал предупреждение, что функцию setcookie() нужно передавать до вывода в браузер любой разметки. И в документации читаю "в скрипте вызовы этой функции должны располагаться прежде остального вывода...". Запускаю код с "преднамеренной ошибкой"

```
<p>text</p>
<?php
  echo "Hallo ";
  setcookie("name1","cookie1");
  echo $_COOKIE["name1"]
?>
```

Никакой ошибки типа

> **Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at...

не появляется.

При первом запуске выводит

> text
>
> Hallo
>
> **Notice**: Undefined index: name1 in **...** on line **5**

а при втором

> text
>
> Hallo cookie1

На локальном сервере все ошибки включены. На удаленных отрабатывает все без Warning'а.

Как получить желаемый **Warning**?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644663/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%83-php#comment917695_644663

Comment: @Visman мне хотелось бы получить пресловутый Warning о том, что я пытаюсь передать куки уже после передачи всех заголовков. а его нет. вот почему?

Comment: Это ваш скрипт целиком или что-то есть до/после?

Comment: @u_mulder цельный php-файл как есть.

Answer (score 3):

Просмотрите настройки php (в php.ini напрямую или через `phpinfo`) и узрейте значение `output_buffering`. Обычно оно установлено в `4096`. Это значит, что все данные размером до 4096 байт включительно буферизуются и посылаются клиенту. Таким образом, если данных мало (а в вашем тестовом скрипте их **очень** мало) весь вывод буферизуется вместе с установкой кук и без проблем выдается клиенту.

А теперь попробуйте установить `output_buffering` в `Off` и наслаждайтесь варнингами.

Comment: огромное спасибо! в php.ini выставил output_buffering = off и (о чудо) появился warning, услаждающий взор.

Comment: output_buffering = 0 и  output_buffering = false так же отрабатывают  исчерпывающе.